# when i build a thread to call the JNI C++ function, the program crashed

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

i want to use these three functions in the sub thread, but the program crashes.

Here are the tree C++ function:

```
//here are three JNI interface 
public native byte[] readImage(String str);
public native byte[] FPGAEnhancement(String str, int flag);
public native byte[] FPGASobel(String str, int flag);
```

These three function can be used correctly in the android program, but when i build a sub thread and use these three functions, the program crashed.

Through test,it seems that this line crashes, the result cant be returned.

```
env->SetByteArrayRegion(jarrRV, 0, length, data);
```

here are the readImage function:

```
Java_wearablepc_ftcl_hit_edu_cn_fpga_MainActivity_readImage(
    JNIEnv *env, jobject, jstring jstr) {
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(jstringTostring(env, jstr), "rb");
if (fp != NULL) {
    int length = getFileLength(fp);
    Log_i("fp length");
    if(length<=0) {
        jbyteArray jarrRV = env->NewByteArray(1);
        return jarrRV;
    } else {
        jbyteArray jarrRV = env->NewByteArray(length);
        jbyte data[length];
        readImage(fp, data, length);
        fclose(fp);
        env->SetByteArrayRegion(jarrRV, 0, length, data);
        return jarrRV;
    }
} else {
    jbyteArray jarrRV = env->NewByteArray(1);
    return jarrRV;
}
```

I guess there might be some thing wrong the way i call the C++ function in the sub thread, but i dont know exactly what it is.Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

When the image file is big, allocating **data[length]** on stack may exhaust the stack, and case crashes. You actually don't need this array at all, you can safely access the bytes of newly created **jarrRV** directly:

```
    jbyteArray jarrRV = env->NewByteArray(length);
    jboolean isCopy;
    jbyte data = env->GetByteArrayElements(env, jarrRV, &isCopy);
    readImage(fp, data, length);
    fclose(fp);
    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(jarrRV, data, 0);
```

Some other comments on your C++ code:

- it seems that in some cases, the file will not be closed.
- In all cases, **jstringTostring()** is likely to leak both native and Java objects. Please don't underestimate the effect of such leak in multithreaded environment.

Comment: that was it. I use the jarrRV instead and it works perfectly! Thanks!